# Need the no. of projects from inside the list(billCustLst) of values which is again inside a list(custLst) of values, java

Tags: java

I am trying to return a number returned by a query, which is running inside a list loop,which again runs inside another list loop. May be I am missing something out which is giving me a wrong data. The code as below.

```
for (CfCust cust : custList) {
    int custCount = 0;
    int billCustCount = 0;
    List<CfBillCust> billCustList = projectMasterDAO.getCfBillCust(bu,cust);
    System.out.println("BillCust List size "+billCustList.size());  
    for (CfBillCust cfBillCust : billCustList) {
        int i = (int) projectMasterDAO.getProjectByCfBillCust(bu, cfBillCust); 
        billCustCount = i + billCustCount;
    }
    custCount = billCustCount;  
    cust.setNoOfProjects(custCount);
    custLst.add(cust);
}
return custLst;
```

The data above is expected to be custCount=14, which is returned from the database calculated separately. The lists are declared globally and few in the snapshot.

Comment: Impossible to say from this snippet. Did you try a debugger? Can you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think (not sure) that what you want is to move `int custCount = 0` outside the 1st `for` loop

Comment: I was wondering why `custCount` and `billCustCount` are two different variables. Aren’t they used for the same thing? Could you make do with the latter alone? Not that it solves your problem, I know.

Comment: Just verified from the database, my expected count was calculated for only one billCustCount from the entire list.I crosschecked for the entire list, and it comes out the right data.The code is working as expected.Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Nice. Please consider whether you either will post your finding as an answer or delete the question.